# MenuFlyout in ListView in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I am working on a universal windows project.

The windows phone 8.1 UI contains a listview. Listviews's source is databound and its datatemplate contains a button. I want to display a MenuFlyout[MenuFlyout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn308516.aspx) when the button is press-and-hold (like [ContextMenu](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msgulfcommunity/archive/2013/05/19/windows-phone-toolkit-context-menu-getting-selected-item-within-a-long-list-selector.aspx) in wp8 toolkit).

My code is :

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ListTemplate" x:Name="ListTemplate">
        <Button Style="{StaticResource ListButtonStyle}">
            <Button.Flyout> 
                <MenuFlyout>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="delete"/>
                </MenuFlyout>
            </Button.Flyout>
        </Button>
    </DataTemplate>

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding List}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListTemplate}">
```

However, this opens the MenuFlyout on clicking the button. How can I change this behavior to press-and-hold event for opening MenuFlyout?

Also, the MenuFlyout zooms in on the Button on which it opens. How can this zooming effect be disabled?

Answer (score 1):

If anybody still interested can use **DrawerLayout**

How to -

1. Add ["DrawerLayout" Nuget Package reference](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DrawerLayout/) to your Project.
2. Add Name space `xmlns:drawerLayout="using:DrawerLayout"`
3. Now divide your page in two part drawer and content

   `<Grid x:Name="RootLayout">`
   `<Grid.RowDefinitions>`
       `<RowDefinition Height="Auto" />`
       `<RowDefinition Height="*" />` 
   `</Grid.RowDefinitions>`
   `<!-- Title Bar -->` 
   `<Grid x:Name="TitleBar" Grid.Row ="0" Height="60">`
       `<!-- —Title Bar Code Goes Here -->`
   `</Grid>` 
   `<!-- Drawer Layout -->`
   `<drawerLayout:DrawerLayout Grid.Row="1"  x:Name="DrawerLayout">`
       `<!-- DrawerLayout code goes here -->`
   `</drawerLayout:DrawerLayout>`
   `</Grid>`

4.Add Drawer Icon

```
<Grid x:Name="TitleBar" Background="#00ADEF" Grid.Row ="0" Height="60">  
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>  
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />  
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />  
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>  

<Image Margin="5"  x:Name="DrawerIcon"  Grid.Column="0" Source="/Assets/drawer_icon.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Tapped="DrawerIcon_Tapped" />  
<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="DRAWER LAYOUT DEMO" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="18"/>  
</Grid>
```

5. Drawe Tap Event

   ```
   private void DrawerIcon_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e) 
   {  
     if (DrawerLayout.IsDrawerOpen)  
       DrawerLayout.CloseDrawer();  
     else  
       DrawerLayout.OpenDrawer();
   }
   ```
6. Thats it.

Note: For more information visit [Here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cb386b/implementing-navigation-drawer-for-windows-phone-8-1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can modify [ContextMenuService](https://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit/ContextMenu/ContextMenuService.cs) from Windows Phone Toolkit.

There is nice tutorial.

http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2014/05/29/Migrating-from-the-Windows-Phone-Toolkit-ContextMenu-to-the-new-Runtime-MenuFlyout.aspx

In short:

- replace `ContextMenu` for `MenuFlyout`
- add event handler `OnElementHolding`

  ```
  private void OnElementHolding(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs args)
  {
      // this event is fired multiple times. We do not want to show the menu twice
      if (args.HoldingState != HoldingState.Started) return;

      FrameworkElement element = sender as FrameworkElement;
      if (element == null) return;

      // If the menu was attached properly, we just need to call this handy method
      FlyoutBase.ShowAttachedFlyout(element);
   }
  ```
- modify `OnMenuFlyoutChanged`

  ```
  private static void OnMenuFlyoutChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
      FrameworkElement element = o as FrameworkElement;
      if (null != element)
      {
          // just in case we were here before and there is no new menu
          element.Holding -= OnElementHolding;

          MenuFlyout oldMenuFlyout = e.OldValue as MenuFlyout;
          if (null != oldMenuFlyout)
          {
              element.SetValue(FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyoutProperty, null);
          }
          MenuFlyout newMenuFlyout = e.NewValue as MenuFlyout;
          if (null != newMenuFlyout)
          {
              element.SetValue(FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyoutProperty, newMenuFlyout);
              element.Holding += OnElementHolding;
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: How to disable zooming effect when the menuflyout opens?

Answer (score 0):

Put button in a grid and attach menuflyout to the grid instead of button.

Like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ListTemplate" x:Name="ListTemplate">
 <Grid Holding="Grid_Holding">
    <Button Style="{StaticResource ListButtonStyle}">
    </Button>
    <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
      <MenuFlyout>
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="delete"/>
      </MenuFlyout>
    </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
 </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

In Code behind:

```
    private void Grid_Holding(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.HoldingState == Windows.UI.Input.HoldingState.Started)
        {
            FrameworkElement frameworkElement = sender as FrameworkElement;
            FlyoutBase flyoutBase = FlyoutBase.GetAttachedFlyout(frameworkElement);
            flyoutBase.ShowAt(frameworkElement);
        }
    }
```